# Resharper 2016.3 how to install a DLL plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I'm trying to install a simple Resharper plugin that I wrote in a DLL that contains one macro.

However I simply cannot find how I'm supposed to install the DLL so I can use the macro.  The only UI Jetbrains seem to provide is to use the Extensions gallery from within Visual Studio.

I'm using Resharper 2016.3 with Visual Studio 2015.

**EDIT:**

I found somewhere online that you can put the DLL directly in the plugins folder and Resharper should pick it up.  Such as location:

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\plugins\MyPlugins\MyPlugins.dll`

However, this also does not appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to package the dll into a .nupkg file, and install it via the Extension Manager. You can add a new feed source to the Extension Manager in ReSharper's options, and point it to a local folder to make it a little easier to install and test. The page on "[Installing Locally](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/Extensions/Deployment/LocalInstallation.html)" in the devguide gives more details.

Comment: I created a .nupkg file (changed lib folder to be DotFiles and put my DLL directly in that folder).  I then directed Extension Manager to look in the local folder that contains the .nupkg file however my plugin is not coming up in the list.  Is there anything else I have left out that I need to do?

Comment: Check out the [troubleshooting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/Extensions/Troubleshooting.html) section, which helps with getting this to show. It's likely that you're missing a dependency on the correct version of the `Wave` package. This is required or the package isn't listed.